# Getting All Data-Bind Values Using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, object, properties

```
    function getDbValue()
{
    alert($('[data-bind]').length);
    alert($('[data-bind][0].data-bind'));
    alert($('[data-bind][0].value'));
    jQuery.each($('[data-bind]'), function(databind,key)
    {
        alert(key);
        alert(databind);
        alert(databind[key].data-bind);
    })

}
```

The above is my function and i want to read all inputs that have the properties data-bind within them for example

```
<input type="text" id="frmIn1-Officer" data-bind="value: AOfficer" class="InputText"/>
```

^ When running my function i would want it to return 'AOfficer' as that is the data-bind value.

So an example is

```
<input type="text" id="frmIn1-Officer" data-bind="value: AOfficer1" class="InputText"/>
<input type="text" id="frmIn1-Officer" data-bind="value: AOfficer2" class="InputText"/>
<input type="text" id="frmIn1-Officer" data-bind="value: AOfficer3" class="InputText"/>
<input type="text" id="frmIn1-Officer" data-bind="value: AOfficer4" class="InputText"/>
<input type="text" id="frmIn1-Officer" data-bind="value: AOfficer5" class="InputText"/>
<input type="text" id="frmIn1-Officer" data-bind="value: AOfficer6" class="InputText"/>
```

And in the for each loop i would like to be able to use the value of data bind..
e.g values[0] = 'AOfficer1'

Sorry if my explanation is slightly confusing, i have the idea in my head perfect but trying to put it in writing is alot harder.

Comment: Have you tried jquery's `.data()` method? `$('input').data('bind');`? http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/

Comment: Yes but when using the for each statement and doing that i get Uncaught TypeError: Object 0 has no method 'data'

Comment: That's probably because in your `for each` loop you're using the native DOM element and not a jQuery object. Only an element wrapped in a jQuery object will have the `.data()` method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery interprets the "data-something" attributes differently than other attributes.  So you should select all your elements and look for their data bindings like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input.InputText').each(function(){
        var input = $(this);
        if ($(input).data().bind) {
            alert($(input).data().bind);
        }
    });
});​
```

Then you can do string manipulation to parse out your values, I'd suggest using JSON and just loading it in like an object.  Here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3NERK/6/

Answer (score 2):

You can search for any element that has a `data-bind` attribute by the jQuery attribute selector - `$("[data-bind]")`, and then iterate on it with `.each()` and construct the `dataBinds` array out of it, stripping the `value:` out of each value.

This will do the trick:

```
dataBinds = [];
$("[data-bind]").each(function(){
     dataBinds.push($(this).attr("data-bind").substring(7));
});​​​​​​
```

I've set up an example of it: http://jsfiddle.net/dvirazulay/YPnwQ/

Answer (score 1):

```
$( "[data-bind]" ).each( function() {
    var elem = $( this );
    alert( elem.data( "bind" ) );
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NhNhK/

Answer (score 1):

Get all elements with `data-bind` attribute: `$('[data-bind]')`

Iterating these elements and manipulating the data-bind attribute:

```
$('[data-bind]').each(function(element,index){
  var data_bind = $(element).data('bind');
  alert(data_bind);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) method with `.each()` to accomplish this.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/EFXJA/1/)

```
$('input').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);

    alert($this.data('bind').replace("value: ", ""));            
});​
```