# getting data from data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I set a data attribute for a user on a link like this

```
  <input type="button" class="btn" data-user={"user": "<%= @user.name %>"}  value="Start" id="game">
```

In the javascript function that listens for the click event, I did a `console.log(e.target)` and it printed the whole thing to the console.

```
<input type="button" class="btn" data-user={"user": "<%= @user.name %>"}  value="Start" id="game">
```

If I do `console.log(e)` i.e. with no e.target, it logs the jquery event, but the data attribute is undefined

```
data: undefined
```

I'm trying to pull the username from the data attribute but don't know how to get it from this

```
<input type="button" class="btn" data-user={"user": "<%= @user.name %>"}  value="Start" id="game">
```

and I don't know why data is undefined when I log just the event.

I'd be very grateful if you can assist me with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show us the **actual** generated markup, that the browser sees. If the "markup" above is what the browser sees, that's not valid markup.

Comment: I don't think any of that is valid markup.

Comment: The attribute value needs to be in quotes: `data-user="{'user': '<%= @user.name %>'}"` or `data-user="<%= @user.name %>"`

Comment: `console.log($(this).attr("data-user"))`

Comment: check this answer with explanation
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11052806/getting-all-data-bind-values-using-jquery

Comment: @MattBall the op has railscode, not markup. Sorry. Problem's fixed anyways as I accepted an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your HTML is ... unique? Instead of this:

```
data-user={"user": "<%= @user.name %>"}
```

Try this:

```
data-user="<%= @user.name %>"
```

Then you can get the data with the standard jQuery [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) technique (since you mentioned jQuery):

```
var user = $('#game').data('user');
```

Comment: Thanks, I actually had the html correct, but then changed it once I did some google searching and found some bad advice on another blog. I didn't realize, though, that you turned the id (#game)into the jquery selector to access the data attribute. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can access the data from the DOM object as follows:

```
var data = $(e.target).attr("data-user");
```